# Can't read directory from owner with 700 permissions

Tags: chmod

I have directory with rwx permission for current user, but he's unable to access it, why?

```
: sudo ls /usr/data/user-data  -lad
drwx------ 9 andrew andrew 4096 May 17 11:13 /usr/data/user-data

: whoami 
andrew

: ls /usr/data/user-data 
ls: cannot access '/usr/data/user-data': Permission denied

: touch /usr/data/user-data/test
touch: cannot touch '/usr/data/user-data/test': Permission denied
```

**EDIT**:

```
: sudo namei -lx /usr/data/user-data
[sudo] password for andrew: 
f: /usr/data/user-data
Drwxr-xr-x root   root   /
drwxr-xr-x root   root   usr
drwxr--r-- root   root   data
drwx------ andrew andrew user-data
```

Comment: `lsblk  |grep user` gives nothing, is that what you mean?

Comment: And permissions may be a problem anywhere up the chain (`/usr/data` as well). Add the output of `namei -lx /usr/data/user-data`, please.

Comment: @muru I attached the output

Comment: There you have it. `/usr/data` isn't accessible by anybody except root. No `x` permissions for anybody else.